# Way to read multiple text files in order using TTS?

Tags: finder, software-recommendation, text, textedit, text-to-speech

I organize many text files by tags using the `Finder` tag system. Sometimes I want to have my Mac speak all of these files by some tag(s). Is there an easier way of going into each text file and manually selecting the text and using the TTS functionality? Alternatively I could use `cd directory && cat * > merged` and then have that file spoken but the files within each tag(s) change dynamically so it's a bit of work every time that seems unnecessary.